# How to clone Windows 10 installation to multiple computers

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, dism

I have tried finding topics about this on here but none of them answered my question:

Is it possible to install Windows 10 on a PC (let's call it PC-01), customize it (add users, wallpaper, installed programs) and then put this install on a USB stick to install Windows 10 like it is configured on PC-01 on a different computer (PC-02,03,04 and so on)?

If yes, is there a tutorial I can follow somehere?

What I tried:

1. Using DISM to convert install.esd to a wim file and edit it with MSMG Toolkit. This failed because the toolkit ignores some commands and it makes me use a completely clean Windows ISO instead of the possibility to convert an existing install to a bootable version.
2. Trying to create a configured install in virtual box and export this using the virtual box extentions, but none of this could help me get a working customized Windows ISO boot.

Can anyone help me with a plan/tutorial how to:

1. Export a configured version of Windows 10 to USB (along with the users, programs and wallpaper customizations).
2. Install that version on multiple laptops so it functions as a clone of the first PC.

Comment: if the computers all have the same hardware then you might just make a disk image of the first computer and write it on each computer.

Comment: @Tooniis They're identical yes, Thinkpad e590's. How do i go about making disk images? Via DISM? And do i install them via disk image recovery from the windows install disk?

Comment: The easiest way is to boot from something like SysRescueCD or even better Clonzilla, then clone the not currently running Windows image to an USB disk, later use the opposite procedure on the target PCs

Comment: @EugenRieck I have tried CloneZilla and it's exactly what i was searching for. It took some time to find out the how and what but with some YouTube tutorials i was able to figure it out. Big thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Officially, if the hardware is all the same then you can use [SysPrep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--system-preparation--overview) to prepare a PC for cloning to other machines. Unofficially, you can usually clone without using SysPrep. You'll also need imaging software. I prefer [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) which offers a free version.